# Lookup within the enum constants by constant specific data

Tags: java, enums

I need to do look up in an *enum* by an int . The enum is as folows :

```
    public enum ErrorCode{

    MissingReturn(1,"Some long String here"),
    InvalidArgument(2,"Another long String here");


    private final int shortCode ;

    private final String detailMessage;

    ErrorCode(shortCode ,detailMessage){
      this.shortCode = shortCode ;
      this.detailMessage= detailMessage;
    } 

    public String getDetailedMessage(){
      return this.detailMessage;
    }    

     public int getShortCode(){
      return this.shortCode ;
    }      

  }
```

Now Is need to have a lookup method that would take an `int` *code* and should return me the `String` message pertaining to that code that is stored in the `Enum`.Passing a *"1"* should return me the String *"Some long String here"*.  What is the best way to implement this functionality?

```
public static String lookUpMessageFromCode(int code){


}
```

P.S: Is the class  `EnumMap` useful for this kind of use case? If yes,please let me know why?

Comment: I have seen this asked (and answered) several times in the last couple of days.

Comment: Are the shortCode values arbitrary (no particular pattern), or are they just 1, 2, 3, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the `int` values that you associated with your `enum`, I would add a static array of `ErrorCode`s, or a static `Map<Integer,ErrorCode>` to your `enum` class, and use it to do a lookup in the message from code method. In your case, an array is more appropriate, because you have values `1` and `2` which are small. I would also change the signature to return `ErrorCode`.

```
private static final ErrorCode[] allErrorCodes = new ErrorCode[] {
    null, MissingReturn, InvalidArgument
};

public static ErrorCode lookUpByCode(int code) {
    // Add range checking to see if the code is valid
    return allErrorCodes[code];
}
```

The callers who need the message would obtain it like this:

```
String message = ErrorCode.lookUpByCode(myErrorCode).getDetailedMessage();
```

Comment: Can't we use `EnumMap`?Please see the last line.

Comment: @Geek No, because `EnumMap` is for mapping *from* an `enum`, while your task calls for mapping from an integer *to* an `enum`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Just for the sake of debate, what is the advantage of creating the ErrorCode array as opposed to just using the Enum values?

Comment: @KevinBowerso This is usually done in the code that uses the `enum`, as opposed to the `enum` implementation itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply iterate through your Enum values and check the code.  This solution lets you utilize the existing `Enum` with out creating another object to manage.

```
public enum ErrorCode {

    MissingReturn(1, "Some long String here"), 
    InvalidArgument(2, "Another long String here");

    private final int shortCode;

    private final String detailMessage;

    ErrorCode(int shortCode, String detailMessage) {
        this.shortCode = shortCode;
        this.detailMessage = detailMessage;
    }

    public String getDetailedMessage() {
        return this.detailMessage;
    }

    public int getShortCode() {
        return this.shortCode;
    }

    public static String lookUpMessageFromCode(int code) {
        String message = null;
        for (ErrorCode errorCode : ErrorCode.values()) {
            if (errorCode.getShortCode() == code) {
                message = errorCode.getDetailedMessage();
                break;
            }
        }
        return message;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ErrorCode.lookUpMessageFromCode(1));
        System.out.println(ErrorCode.lookUpMessageFromCode(2));
    }

}
```

**One thing to note**

The `Enum` constructor is missing the type information regarding its parameters.

```
ErrorCode(int shortCode, String detailMessage) {
    this.shortCode = shortCode;
    this.detailMessage = detailMessage;
}
```

Comment: your program would not scale well if there are lots of constants in the enum. dasblinkenlight's answer would do well in that regard since the look up will happen in O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
     public static String lookUpMessageFromCode(int code){
     for(ErrorCode ec:ErrorCode.values()){
         if(ec.shortCode==code)
             return ec.detailMessage;
     }
     return null;
 }
```